# Alternative module to Select (or Other) in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

Select (or other) has a demerit that when you add something other than the given options, the new option which you have written in text box, gets added in the list. So when next time when you see the drop down, the option which you added previously is now showing in the drop down list.

**Here is detailed description**:

When i add "Stack Overflow" in the text box of other option.

[image]

**Now you will see this option in the list:**

[image]

I have gone through the issues related to the "Select (or other) module and found out that this is the issue of this module"

What can be solution to this failure of this module?

Answer (score 0):

[CCK Selct Other](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_select_other) can be a better option to avoid this problem, but in my case i have one additional requirement.

I wanted "Other" field should be hidden until the user selects "Other" option. But in CCK it is always open. So instaed i used [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) Module.